# How do I code 2 seperate categorical variables into a single one in R?

Tags: r, while-loop

I have two continuous variables that I dummy coded into a categorical variable with 2 levels. Each of these variables are coded either 0 or 1 for low and high levels of this variable. Both variables were z-scored to know if they fell below or above the mean.

```
MeanAboveAvo <- ifelse(Dataframeforstudy2$avo < 0, 0, 1)

MeanAboveAnx <- ifelse(Dataframeforstudy2$anx < 0, 0 , 1)
```

My question is how do I dummy code these two variables together? I want to create a single variable with 4 different levels using these two variables (MeanAboveAvo & MeanAboveAnx). I want a single variable that is coded with either 1,2,3,4 and the 1 is (0,0), 2 is (0,1), 3 is (1,0) and 4 is (1,1).

My code is this:

```
stats <- while(MeanAboveAnx = 0 || MeanAboveAvx = 1) {


   if(MeanAboveAnx = 0 & MeanAboveAvo = 0 ){
   1
} 

else if (MeanAboveAnx = 0 & MeanAboveAvo = 1){
 2
}

  else if(MeanAboveAnx = 1 & MeanAboveAvo = 0){
     3
 } 

else {
    4
   }}
```

It is not coding it at all and I am getting an error message. What can I do differently to get the results I want?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categorical variables in in R don’t need to be numeric (and making them so has several drawbacks!): there’s consequently no need for your `ifelse`:

```
MeanAboveAvo <- Dataframeforstudy2$avo < 0
MeanAboveAnx <- Dataframeforstudy2$anx < 0
```

Next, the code using these encodings contains multiple mistakes:

1. It’s not clear what the `while` here is supposed to mean.
2. All `=` signs need to be converted to `==` because you’re performing *comparisons*.
3. `if`, unlike `ifelse`, isn’t vectorised so you cannot use it to assign its result to a vector of length > 1.

If I understand you correctly, then the following is one (canonical) way of encoding the `stats`:

```
stats <- paste(MeanAboveAvo, MeanAboveAnx)
```

This converts the logical vectors into character vectors and concatenates them element-wise. Once again, it is unnecessary (and unconventional!) in R to convert these categories into a numeric variable; though it may make sense to convert it to a factor via `as.factor`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Not only did you give me the right answer, but you helped me understand what I need to learn with programming. I made it a lot more complicated than it had to be.

Answer (score 4):

Base R has function `interaction` precisely for this type of problem. The code below can become a one-liner, I leave it like this in order to make it more clear.

```
f <- with(df, interaction(anx, avo, lex.order = TRUE))
as.integer(f)
# [1] 1 2 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 2
```

## Edit.

I was using the data in [TomasIsCoding's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779857/8245406) answer, here is a solution more to the question's problem, with `anx` and `avo` as z-scores. Thanks to @KonradRudolph for his comment.

```
f <- with(df, interaction(as.integer(anx < 0), 
                          as.integer(avo < 0), 
                          lex.order = TRUE))
f
# [1] 1.1 0.1 0.1 1.0 0.0 0.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.0
#Levels: 0.0 0.1 1.0 1.1

as.integer(f)
# [1] 4 2 2 3 1 2 4 4 4 3
```

**Data.**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(anx = rnorm(10), avo = rnorm(10))
```

Comment: I always forget about `interaction`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas OK but now I need to ask: why the conversions? As noted in my answer, they’re not only unnecessary but actually unconventional and generally problematic (because some packages, e.g. ggplot2, assume that numeric variables are continuous rather than categorical).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, that's true and my option is always not to convert. I did it for no good reason, except maybe to have the factor's levels equal to what the OP posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the mapping rule to code the `anx` and `avo`, you actually don't need while loop, since yours is a shifted mapping from binary to decimal. In this case, you can do it like below

```
df <- within(df,code <- 2*anx + avo + 1)
```

such that

```
> df
   anx avo code
1    0   0    1
2    0   1    2
3    0   0    1
4    0   0    1
5    0   1    2
6    1   0    3
7    1   0    3
8    1   0    3
9    1   1    4
10   0   1    2
```

**Dummy Data**

```
df <- structure(list(anx = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L
), avo = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
as.integer(factor(paste0(MeanAboveAvo, MeanAboveAnx)))
```

For example:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(0:1, 10, T) # [1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
y <- sample(0:1, 10, T) # [1] 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
as.integer(factor(paste0(x, y)))
# [1] 2 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 1 1
```